# Where would 72590 be considered On Topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Where would

[Autoscan network is not working with two or more NIC's on Windows 7 and 10](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/72590/autoscan-network-is-not-working-with-two-or-more-nics-on-windows-7-and-10)

be considered "on topic" so I can re-post it in the proper place?

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned in a comment, you could try asking this on https://www.serverfault.com for a business network, although I'm not sure if it's a good fit there. You should check their help center to see what type of questions are on topic there.

Comment: Hi Teun,  I really need to get my question posted in the proper place.  I have no idea what sf means.  Would you give me a link?  Many thanks, -T

Comment: Sorry, autocomplete doesn't work here, I corrected it now. Though it was already mentioned in the comment on your original question. Keep in mind that all StackExchange sites operate mostly independent of each other. We can only determine what's on topic here, we're not able to help find everyone the correct place for their questions.

Comment: Hi Teun,  Thank you!  I just reposted over at https://serverfault.com/questions/1054195/autoscan-network-is-not-working-with-two-or-more-nics-on-windows-7-and-10.  I am glad I did not waste five hours documenting and writing up a question just to get it bounced.  Hopefully not again.  -T